# Getting NaN during calculation

Tags: javascript, nan

I am trying to calculate the total of a selection of CDs in addition of P&P.  The code I'm using is coming to a total of NaN?

Very confused here. what am I doing wrong?

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var Collection method = document.getElementById('collection').value +
    var select CDs = document.getElementById('selectCD').value;
    var total = document.getElementById('total');
    total.value = 'collection'(total) + 'selectCD'(total);
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MPtN9/1/) with the full code.

Comment: I would suggest you have a look at your error console: there are several syntax errors in your code.

Comment: you have added + instead of ;  < var Collection method = document.getElementById('collection').value +

Comment: This code has ***lots*** of syntax errors!  First, variable names *cannot* contain spaces.  Also, you have a trailing `+` in your first line.

Comment: you must have many syntax errors !

Comment: What do you expect `'collection'(total)` and `'selectCD'(total)` to do?  That is not correct syntax!

Comment: I think your code is a little bit confusing. Anyway, `var collection ... + var select ... ` is not correctly coded. This can be one of your problems.

Comment: I doubt this function is giving a total of NaN, this function won't even run.

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle `collection` and `selectCD` are divs (not inputfields) *containing* inputfields. You can't do `divElm.value`.

Then the php-code in your fiddle would normally be able to output more then one cd, so you'd need to add the totals of the selected cd's to.

The minimum changes needed to get *your* code working are:

```
function calculateTotal(){
    var coll = document.getElementsByName('deliveryType'), 
         cds = document.getElementsByName('cd[]'),
       cdTot = 0,
           L = coll.length;
    while(L--){if(coll[L].checked){   //get shipping costs
        coll=Number(coll[L].getAttribute('title')); break; 
    }         }
    L=cds.length;
    while(L--){if(cds[L].checked){    //add total prices
        cdTot += Number(cds[L].getAttribute('title')); 
    }         }
    //  output total
    document.getElementById('total').value = coll + cdTot;
}
```

Also you'd want to set some more triggers to function `calculateTotal` (from the shipping costs and selected cd's; this way, if they change, the total-field will update to).
See this *[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MPtN9/4/)* with these changes (and *some* other fixes) based on your fiddle so you can get motivated seeing it (calculation) in action.

However I do hope this is for a school-question and not for a live webshop. I would re-think my strategy as I think you are currently working your way to a big security hole.

Good luck!

Comment: I prefer using `parseInt`/`parseFloat` instead of `Number()`.  `Number()` will give `NaN` if the string is not a valid number, whereas `parseInt` will try to parse it anyway.  `parseInt('123abc', 10)` is `123`, but `Number('123abc')` is `NaN`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Indeed, it's just what one needs aka just what floats your boat. I also love putting `+` in front of the string or multiply the string by 1 or.. there are so many way's : http://jsperf.com/convert-string-to-number-techniques/2

Comment: @GitaarLAB thanks for your kind response. the solution you provided for some reason still does not work in my code. maybe if I provide the whole code you can help? kind regards

Comment: You could put it in a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), update your question with the link to that jsfiddle and I'll look at it tomorrow (if someone else didn't do it before me).